# How Uber processes orders?

Tags: java, python

Lets say you created an order. Since Uber is a very dynamic system, one should constantly check if there are available drivers for you.

If orders are saved as a some collection (e.g. in MySQL table and etc), then one should iterate that collection again and again and try to match client with driver, because some driver that was busy 1 second ago can suddenly become available.

My question - how orders are saved? And more important question - how orders are being iterated?

Comment: see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)

Comment: @gnat This isn't a customer-service-related question.

Comment: Consider that there could be a whole server whose job is to match drivers and customers.

Comment: @user253751, absolutely agree with you, this is a question about system design, thanks for solution option

Comment: I do think you should edit the question so it's not asking about Uber. Instead, ask about what you want to do.

Comment: I can think of two reasons this is a poor fit for a Q&A site: firstly, you're asking for details of a particular commercial system, which only employees of that company could give you, and they might or might not be willing to do so; secondly, you're essentially asking for a description of the entire application, which would be far too much to fit into one answer. To fit this format, you need to focus on a particular design problem, and explain why Uber is a relevant example of that specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start thinking in terms of "MySQL tables", the first step is to clearly identify the entities and relationships in your system. I don't know anything about Uber's actual process, and there are many more factors than I'll mention here, but at its core, we have this:

1. Drivers. A driver is an entity that has a `Location` and `Availability`. The driver will constantly update the system with those two properties, even every second.
2. Customers. A customer requests a ride, which should query the available drivers in the relevant area.

Now that you have that, the question is a bit more focused: "how do I efficiently query a collection of entities based on geographic location". You want a query that's efficient enough to run every second for as long as the customer searches for a ride. Given those parameters, we need the following:

1. A [spatial database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database). These are databases optimized for geographical queries. MySQL supports some spatial query features, according to the wikipedia entry I linked to, but there might be more specialized, optimized DBs out there. This will allow searches for "In Xkm radius and Available=true" to be efficient, without having to *iterate* all entries. In general, a proper data architecture will try to filter and query, not *iterate* much.
2. An in-memory DB. Your data might be persisted to disk, but for decent performance when you have many thousands of users querying thousands of drivers, you'll probably want a set of machines with lots of RAM holding all that spatial information in memory. Again, some of the spatial DBs from point #1 probably have that feature, such as Redis+GeoAPI, but you'll have to research the best option here.

So what do we have? An architecture that's kept dynamically cached in memory to allow for quick searches, using a database system that's optimized for location-based queries, allowing you to narrow down the search without iterating through all entries.

Comment: The driver locations are changed often, not sure how Redis caching could help here